# PL/SQL Procedure Use String Select Statement in for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am building a procedure, where I`m first creating a select statement and store it in an VARCAHR variable. 
I now want to execute that query and store the whole result set in an variable to loop through it or use directly in a for loop.
I only find examples where the Select is hard written in the for loop definition.
How do i exchange the Select statement with my variable that holds my select statement?

```
for r IN (SELECT ... FROM ...)
loop
   --do sth;
end loop;
```

how i want to use it :

```
statement := 'SELECT .... FROM ...';
for r IN (statement) -- HOW TO DO THIS
    loop
       --do sth;
    end loop;
```

Comment: Look for `EXECUTE` statement in Pl/PgSQL...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? for r in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(statement) dows not work

Comment: check this:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS00001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a dynamic ref cursor, you need to define everything explicitly:

```
declare 
    sqlstring long := 'select 123 as id, ''demo'' as somevalue from dual where dummy = :b1';
    resultset sys_refcursor;

    type demo_rectype is record
        ( id integer
        , somevalue varchar2(30) );

    demorec demo_rectype;
begin
    open resultset for sqlstring using 'X';

    loop
        fetch resultset into demorec;
        exit when resultset%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line('id=' || demorec.id || ' somevalue=' || demorec.somevalue);
    end loop;

    close resultset;
end;
```

You can parse the cursor and figure out the column names and datatypes with DBMS_SQL. Example here: [www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml)